# magento plugin storing location

Tags: magento, plugins

We are in a process of magento extension creation. But have doubt on plugin files storage location. Is it in the development instance folder or magento connect server after packaging?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Look up the documentation.

Comment: @DieterMeemken i have created a sample pluin and able o do both packaging and publishing. The storing location was not mentioned in the developer doc.

Comment: @Enigmativity i have gone through the docs. The created extensions storing location want mentioned in that. Saw a comment also in a a site "store and sell extension in your site", thats why i got confused

Answer (score 0):

"Is it in the development instance folder or magento connect server after packaging?"

**It will be in the Magento connect server**. Extension can be accessed by your Magento account My Account -> developers -> My Extensions.